# mongoose.save() does not save it's data

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose

I tried this problem for 5 hours but I could not find what the problem is

in -routes/users.ts,

"targetUser.token = token" is working so console.log(targetUser) shows me the updated user data

but, targetUser.save() does not update this data to MONGO DB... why!

-User.ts-

```
import mongoose, { Document, Schema } from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

const saultRounds = 10;

const userSchema = new Schema({
 name: {
   type: String,
   maxlength: 50,
 },
 email: {
   type: String,
   trim: true,
   unique: 1,
 },
 password: {
   type: String,
   minglength: 5,
 },
 lastname: {
   type: String,
   maxlength: 50,
 },
 role: {
   type: Number,
   default: 0,
 },
 cart: {
   type: Array,
   default: [],
 },
 history: {
   type: Array,
   default: [],
 },
 image: String,
 token: {
   type: String,
 },
 tokenExp: {
   type: Number,
 },
});

export interface UserBaseDocumentType extends Document {
 name: string;
 email: string;
 password: string;
 lastname: string;
 role: number;
 art: [];
 history: [];
 image: string;
 token: string;
 tokenExp: string;
 comparePassword(plainPassword: string): Promise<boolean>;
}

userSchema.pre<UserBaseDocumentType>("save", function (next) {
 let user = this;

 if (user.isModified("password")) {
   bcrypt.genSalt(saultRounds, function (err, salt) {
     if (err) return next(err);

     bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
       if (err) return next(err);

       user.password = hash;

       next();
     });
   });
 }
});

//methods//////////////////////////////////////////////////

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (plainPassword: string) {
 let user = this as UserBaseDocumentType;
 return bcrypt.compare(plainPassword, user.password);
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////export this model////////////////////////////
export default mongoose.model<UserBaseDocumentType>("User", userSchema);
///////////////////////////////////////////
```

-routes/users.ts

```
import express from "express";
import User from "../models/User";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const user = new User(req.body);

  user.save((err, userData) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, err });

    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, userData });
  });
});

router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then((targetUser) => {
    if (!targetUser) {
      res.json({ loginState: false, message: "there is no matched user" });
    } else {
      targetUser.comparePassword(req.body.password).then((result) => {
        if (!result) {
          res.json({ loginState: false, message: "wrong password" });
        } else {
          let token = jwt.sign(targetUser._id.toHexString(), "secret");
          targetUser.token = token;
          console.log(targetUser);
          targetUser.save();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

export default router;
```

-index.ts-

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const mongoDBAccessKey = require("./config/key");
import userRouter from "./routes/users";

//initializing app (const app = express())
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
////////////////////////////////////////////

//initializing mongoose
mongoose
  .connect(mongoDBAccessKey.mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB is now connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
///////////////////////////////////////

//routes
app.use("/users", userRouter);
////////////////////////////////////////
//PORT
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening port ${port}`);
});
//////////////////////////////////////
```

I guess typescript does not understand mongoose's Document type so it's save() methods doesn't work.

can anyone help me please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is in your pre save middleware. If you look carefuly, next() only gets triggered if your updates include the password. If your update object doesn't include that field, the middleware will prevent the save method to be finally implemented, as next() was never called.
You can check if this is the problem quite quickly, just by adding next() also for the updates that don't involve the password:

```
userSchema.pre<UserBaseDocumentType>("save", function (next) {
 let user = this;
 if (user.isModified("password")) {
   bcrypt.genSalt(saultRounds, function (err, salt) {
     if (err) return next(err);
     bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
       if (err) return next(err);
       user.password = hash;
       next();
     });
   });
 }
 next();
});
```

Comment: Oh my God you save my life really thanks. it is exactly the problem of "next()" haha... but I don't know why next() ignores the upper "if" condition. so I have to else{next()} and then problem was solved. really weird